# Ingress unable to find backend service in Kubernetes v1.21.5

Tags: express, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, skaffold

I am using Kubernetes v1.21.5 on docker. The following is my ingress YAML file

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: triver.dev  
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /service/account/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I am running an auth srv image and the following is its YAML file

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: triver/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'mongodb://mongo-srv:27017/auth'
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

but when I try to send a request to any route that I created in auth service for example I created a triver.dev/service/account/signup post express router for a user to signup. When I try to send a post request to the route through Postman it gives an error (404) of ECONNRefused. Couldn't send a request. Why is it happening? (My postman is working fine. It's not an issue on the postman end.)

**What am I doing wrong**

The app works but I just can't access the route. It's definitely an ingress issue. Can someone help me, please? This is a very important project.

[This is what show up when I use the command 'kubectl get ingress'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJOgF.png)

[Everything works fine when I run the application using skaffold dev.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmdFl.png)

Comment: Your ingress only directs requests of the form `/api/users/?(.*)` to your back-end, so in Postman you'll need to send your request to `triver.dev/api/users/service/account/signup`, or better yet, change your ingress path to simply `/api/`

Comment: Sorry, @code_monk that was my bad. I updated the question. I am sending the request to the right URL path but it gives me back a 404 error.

Comment: If you're getting a 404 error with ECONNRefused, I'll bet the ingress is working fine, but it's the connection between the express server and mongoDB server that is failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's due to you have not mentioned the hostname into the ingress, also make sure your ingress controller is running

example ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: example-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

**host: hello-world.info**

Reference : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

you can also checkout : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

if you have set default backend set in ingress and **host** is not issue

make sure you are sending the request on **HTTP** instead of **HTTPS**

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
```

as you are **not** using the certificate **SSL/TLS** so please try the URL with **HTTP**

Comment: thank you for your reply. I added in the host as well as tried to send the request using HTTP instead of HTTPS. But no change in the error. It still says ECONN Refused

Comment: did you try by the port forwardin to debug issue it is working with port forward ? `kubectl port-forward svc/auth-srv 3000:3000`

Comment: I still don't understand the problem. This has never happened to me before. I ran the project 2 months back with the exact same code. It had worked back then but now it isn't working after updating the ingress to networking.k8s.io/v1. So I believe it's an ingress issue. But I checked GitHub issues, this issue was apparently resolved in april 2021.

Comment: I tried the port forward as you mentioned still the same issue persists.

Comment: check the logs of appliation hope that is no closing the request plus you can remove the regex from ingress config if not required.

Comment: I checked the log file. The requests aren't even reaching the application.

Comment: The application has got 0 requests since it has been started in the log file while I sent well above 100 requests till now.

Comment: check the log of Nginx ingress controller in K8s pod, also try removing the regex.

Comment: I tried removing the regex as well. I have updated the question with info which I believe is the problem. My ingress ports is 80 and address is nill. I believe this is the issue.

Comment: are you on localhost or which could ?

Comment: I am on localhost. I am running this project locally

Comment: if using the minikube `minikube addons enable ingress`

Comment: your ingress controller running ? you installed it or using default one ?

Comment: or else you need add the entry into the etc/host file. : example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress

Comment: I am using the default one which I get after running ingress-srv.yaml file. I also added the entry into the /etc/hosts file. I mentioned triver.dev in the /etc/hosts file.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 triver.dev this is what I added to my /etc/hosts file

Comment: I am running kubernetes using docker desktop. I am not using Minikube

Comment: I added an image to the question. My application works but I can't access it. Skaffold shows that everything including the ingress service is configured. NO errors or any bugs when I run the application

Comment: thanks a lot for trying to help me solve this issue but turns out that I just had to reinstall ingress. I still don't know what the problem was but ingress was installed on my system and it was working. After I reinstalled ingress the problem was resolved